# where to release NSArray used in different methods of same class

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my iOS project i am creating an `NSArray` that can contains integer values. There are several functions in this class that do their task on that `NSArray`. So i thought to create `NSArray` as private attribute of that class. In `viewDidLoad` i am allocating memory to this array i.e

```
myArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

`myArray` will be used in several method of this class. When i analyze my code it shows memory leak as i am allocating `myArray` and not releasing it.

If i write `[myArray release]` in `dealloc` or `viewDidUnload` warning still there. If i release `myArray` in last method of class that is using this array, xCode wont allow me to do.

Here is How i am declaring it in my class
.h file

```
@interface FightVC : UIViewController
{
    NSArray *myArray;
}
```

I want to know what is possible solution of this. other then using `autorelease` . I don't want to make it public so i am not writing this array as property.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `@property` doesn't automatically make a variable public... You can create a property inside of a class as an instance variable to have it be 'private'

Comment: How exactly are you declaring myArray? Is it an `@property` of the class? Are you declaring an instance variable?

Comment: I am declaring as instance variable

Comment: Could you provide the code for your class? It’s hard to tell what’s going on without some better context.

Comment: Please find code in question, i added just now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a private `@property` as mentioned in the other answer is probably the nicest and cleanest way to do this. Raw instance variables aren’t a very modern way of doing things. However, if you are going down that road, you can implement a getter for your ivar in which you release the old ivar and retain the new one:

```
- (void)setMyArray:(NSArray *)array {
    [myArray release];
    myArray = [array retain];
}
```

That’s the typical pattern anyway (which is what having an `@property` does for you automatically).

After that, you can create the array, use the setter, and then release the object:

```
NSArray *newArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
[self setMyArray:newArray];
[newArray release];
```

That should keep the analyzer from squawking at you. A few things stick out to me though:

1) `[[NSArray alloc] init]` isn’t likely to do what you want it to do. It’s going to create an empty, immutable array. You probably either want an NSMutableArray, or you want to instantiate it with objects already in it using a different initializer.

2) `NSArray`s aren’t really suited for holding integers themselves, they hold objects. You can either use an `NSPointerArray` or you can put the integers into NSNumbers and put them into an `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0):

To make a property private, you have to create an anonymous category.

In your .m file:

```
@interface myClass ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *myPrivateArray;

@end

@implementation myClass

// Class code here

@end
```

To release your array, simply set the property to nil.

```
self.myPrivateArray = nil;
```